# Because of Content-Security-Policy I need to set the style of an embedded svg-file with an external javascript. How?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, content-security-policy

I have a large svg-image embedded in a html-file. Up until now, the svg-stylesheet is inside the svg-file. It looks like this:

```
.canvas {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    clip-rule: evenodd;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
.path {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #999999;
    stroke-width: 118;
}
.rect {
    fill: #00CC00;
    stroke: #333333;
    stroke-width: 118;
}
.trans {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: transparent;
}
```

Works just fine. :) However, because of the Content-Security-Policy of my website, this has to move to an external JavaScript file. As most of you probably know: an external stylesheet doesn't work with a svg-file embedded in a html-file. So this is the JavaScript I came up with:

```
function myFunction(){

    const one = document.getElementById('canvas');
    one.style.background = '#CCCCCC';

    const two = document.getElementById('path');
    two.style.fill = '#FFFFFF';
    two.style.stroke = '#999999';

    const three = document.getElementById('rect');
    three.style.fill = '#00CC00';
    three.style.stroke = '#333333'; }

   window.onload = myFunction;
```

Does its job. However, I can't get the other stuff (clip-rule, fill-rule, image-rendering, shape-rendering, text-rendering and stroke-width) working. Does anyone know how to solve this? Or maybe my approach is all wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Shelley.

P.S. The use of unsafe-inline or data: in the CSP is not an option. They enable XSS attacks...

Comment: Hyphenated names must be converted to lowerCamelCase, for example, `one.style.clipRule = "evenodd"`. Was that your problem?

Comment: No, it was not. But I did figure it out. I just had to replace `one.style.background = ` by `one.style = `. Then you can put in there whatever you want. :-)